# Reference to Xna 4.0 library

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, xna, mscorlib

I'm creating program to compile scripts(using Xna library) at runtime.
But I have error after I add a reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll;

Code to add reference:

```
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Collections.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("WindowsGame1.exe");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll");
```

Script code which I want to compile :

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace WindowsGame1
{
    class Enemy         
    {
       public Enemy()
       {
       }
    }
}
```

When I run program, I have this error :

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)`

I try to delete mscorlib.dll from  solution References but when I did this, I saw this error :

`e:\Project\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\bin\x86\Release\WindowsGame1.exe: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)`

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: With posts like this year's ago, I wonder why you are still using XNA, http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php

Comment: Even when, I use Monogame I have the same error

Comment: can you run a MonoGame sample first to check if anything is wrong with your Windows environment? Then you can move to your own project.

Comment: Sample works fine without any errors.